# discord.js collector.on('end') not posting the collected things in the channel he supposed to

Tags: javascript, discord.js

My Problem is that everything works fine but the collector doesnt send the hole thing in the channel i decided to. I give you here the full code so you can understand the system. But the Problem is only the collector.on(end) function.
The Error here is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0Ews.jpg
I really tried everything but i dont know how to fix it. :)

```
    if (reaction.emoji.name === "✅"){
    const dmChannel = await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id)
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('4D Artworks Bestellung')
        .setDescription('Wähle bitte aus was du haben willst indem du unten reagierst. \n\n 1️⃣ » Einzeln auswählen \n 2️⃣ » Paket \n 3️⃣ » Blowjob')
        .setColor('GREEN')
        let msgEmbed = await dmChannel.send(embed)
        msgEmbed.react('1️⃣')
        msgEmbed.react('2️⃣')
        msgEmbed.react('3️⃣')     
  }
}

    if (reaction.emoji.name === '1️⃣') {
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        const questions = [`Sneertu1`, `Sneertu2`, `Sneertu3`];
        const dmChannel = await user.send('**Willkommen, beantworte alle Fragen um eine Bestellung aufzugeben.**')
        const collector = dmChannel.channel.createMessageCollector((msg) => msg.author.id == user.id); 
        let i = 0;
        const res = [];
        dmChannel.channel.send(questions[0])
        collector.on('collect', async(msg) => {
            if(questions.length == i) return collector.stop('MAX');
            const answer = msg.content;
            res.push({ question: questions[i], answer });
            i++;
            if(questions.length == i) return collector.stop('MAX');
            else {
                dmChannel.channel.send(questions[i]);
            }
        });

        collector.on('end', async(collected, reason) => {
            if(reason == 'MAX') {
                if(reaction.guild.id === "809490902389227520"){
                let channelId = '813887506256494692'    
                const data = client.channels.cache.get(channelId);
                await data.send(`${reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id)} hat eine Bestellung abgegeben!\n\n${res.map(d => `**${d.question}** \n ${d.answer}`).join("\n\n")}`)
            }
        }
        })
    }
```

Comment: reaction doesn't have guild property go for `reaction.message.guild.id`

Comment: doesnt work
https://imgur.com/v4v0h4g

Comment: Okay I just noticed that you are doing in DM, okay then you should be able to do that `reaction.client.guilds.cache.get("guildID")`. if id wasn't null it `if(reaction.guild.id === "809490902389227520")` would never work because you are doing it on dm channel

Comment: thank you i think that problem is now gone now is a new one. Look here
https://imgur.com/PFgvrY8

Comment: Use the same trick, change `client.channels` to `reactions.client.channels`

Comment: thanks you are great!

Comment: Only one question left.
Now it doesnt work with the data.send
Have a look: https://imgur.com/62cRjXF

Comment: console.log(data) and watch if it finds the channel

Comment: How? Doesnt work @Cursed

Comment: what do you mean what does the console return?

Comment: How should i console.log it? @cursed